# Не получается отправить HTML код в базу данных

Tags: url, ajax, html

Здравствуйте!

Ломаю голову над одним делом. Я посылаю ajax запрос серверу, содержащий HTML в GET переменной, если отправляю запрос вида

```
http://mysait.ru/index.php?val=<img src="URL">
```

то такой запрос принимается и добавляется в базу данных, а запрос вида

```
http://mysait.ru/index.php?val=&%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E8.15%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20id=%22nocurrent%22%20time=%2240%22%...`
```

Не принимается. Что делать, мне HTML передать, ой как надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Шифруйте строку с HTML в base64 (получится что-то вроде `http://mysait.ru/index.php?val=PGltZyBzcmM9IlVSTCI+`), а на сервере расшифровывайте обратно.
2. Используйте POST для отправки данных (совместимо с п.1)

---

**UPD0.**

Если для ajax используете jquery, то для кодировки в base64 можно воспользоваться [одноименным плагином](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/base64). Для декодирования у PHP есть функция [base64_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.base64-decode.php).

Comment: @Nafate а можно поподробней про base64 и, как им пользоваться?